# Angular 4 Poll / Stream Data from service within ngOnInit

Tags: angular, angular2-observables, ngoninit

I would like to use AngularJS 4 to stream data from an API.  When I first call the API there is no data, but eventually more results will be returned over a 15 - 30 second period.

**Here is my component:**

```
export class ResultsComponent implements OnInit {
    results: Results;

    constructor(
        private searchService: SearchService,
        private route: ActivatedRoute
    ) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {

        this.route.params
            .switchMap((params: Params) => 
        this.searchService.getResultsObservable(params['searchKey']))
            .subscribe(data => { this.results = data; });
}
```

**Here are my service calls:**

I'm using the Observable call above, but I've included the Promise call as well.

```
getResults(searchKey: string): Promise<Results> {
    const url = `${this.apiUrl}/${searchKey}/0`;
    return this.http.get(url)
            .toPromise()
            .then(response => response.json() || {})
            .catch(this.handleError);
}

getResultsObservable(searchKey: string): Observable<Results> {
    const url = `${this.apiUrl}/${searchKey}/0`;
    return this.http
            .get(url)
            .map(response => response.json() || {});
}
```

I believe I need to use the Observable call, but I'm not sure how I need to handle the call within the component.

Comment: `AngularJS` and `Angular 4` are two different frameworks. What you are using here is `Angular 4`. You might want to edit your question and replace `AngularJS` with `Angular.`

Comment: @mridula Thanks!  I've updated the question.

Comment: What is the exact problem you are having? I can't really tell from reading your question :(. Your observable call handling from the component looks fine.

Comment: @Nehal I'm not sure how I can pass my SearchKey as a param, then stream the results back to my view.  Currently, I just call the service once during the ngOnInit(), should I be doing this differently?  How does my component know to keep checking for more data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks, @mridula for getting me on the right track.  After some research, I see the best solution is to use an **IntervalObservable**:

```
subscription: Subscription;

ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(
      (params: Params) => {
        this.subscription = this.getResults((params['searchKey'])).subscribe(
          (response) => {
            console.log(response);
            //your business logic for each loop
            //once your are done
            this.stopInterval();
        }
      }
    );
  }
);

getResults(searchKey: string): {
      return IntervalObservable
      .create(1000) //1 second interval
      .flatMap(() => {
      return this.http.get('[API_URL]/' + searchKey).map(response => response.json());
  });
}

stopInterval(){
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you have to keep getting data from the server after specific intervals (say, 15 seconds), you can try this:

```
private keepGettingDataFromServer() {
    this.intervalLoop = setInterval (() => {
            this.getResultsObservable.subscribe(res => {
                //handle the response here
            })
        }
    }, 1500)
}

getResultsObservable(searchKey: string): Observable<Results> {
    const url = `${this.apiUrl}/${searchKey}/0`;
    return this.http
        .get(url)
        .map(response => response.json() || {});
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.intervalLoop) {
        clearInterval(this.intervalLoop);
    }
}
```

I can think of another way too, if your server is `ASP .NET`, you can use [SignalR](https://blog.sstorie.com/integrating-angular2-and-signalr-part-1/) to subscribe to a channel and get notified when you receive the expected data.

Comment: Thanks, @mridula for getting me on the right track!